# Foundation: Searchbar in Navbar stretches too far below

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation

I have a design issue with my Foundation navbar:

[image: navbar]

Basically, the search bar is off (you can tell that it stretches way to far to the bottom of the navbar. My question is: are there any CSS tricks or bugs I am not noticing that is causing this error? My Foundation code should be mostly the same as the Zurb Foundation Doc so I don't know what's going on...

The url for our website is http://calapps2.herokuapp.com and the code is below (in Haml).
Note: As I am developing an App in Rails, I like to have minimal CSS so I actually don't use any extra CSS besides the Foundation code.

```
%nav.top-bar{:data=>{:topbar => true}}
  %ul.title-area
    %li.name
      %h1=link_to "CalApps", '/'
  %section.top-bar-section
    %ul.left
      %li.has-form
        .row.collapse
          .large-8.small-9.columns
            %input{:type => "text", :placeholder => "Find"}
          .large-4.small-3.columns
            %a.alert.button.expand{:href => "#"} Search
      %li.divider
```

All my CSS is contained with one statement:

```
@import "foundation_and_overrides";
/* Add imports of custom sass/scss files here */
```

The aforementioned CSS code is contained here: https://github.com/CS169-badjr/calapps/blob/master/app/assets/stylesheets/application.css.scss

On the same folder is the code for Foundation, normalize.css, and other goodies.

Comment: There is no relevant CSS besides the Foundation code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is height and margin-bottom property set to the inbox i.e. for class
`input[type="text"], input[type="password"], input[type="date"], input[type="datetime"], input[type="datetime-local"], input[type="month"], input[type="week"], input[type="email"], input[type="number"], input[type="search"], input[type="tel"], input[type="time"], input[type="url"], textarea`

If try to update or give specific height and marging to the inbox it will not extend beyond your nav bar.

example `CSS`

```
large-8 input
{
  height: 28px;
    margin: 0;
}
```

You can also try element style in case you can not modify the given `CSS`.

Comment: Can you tell me why this can not be used? so that I can provide other solution.

Comment: after experimenting it out, I realized that it is a problem of height, not margin. Strange...

Comment: also your solution works on Chrome Dev. Tools but not on my actual local server instance.

Comment: The problem will definitely be solved by height but the link shared has some margin as well. So in case you have some element exactly below the search box then it would take the blank space(which is margin given to search box). Can you please share the CSS, that is written on your local instance?

Comment: Here is all my CSS:
@import "foundation_and_overrides";
/* Add imports of custom sass/scss files here */

Comment: i can not see CSS here. It seems some kind of path. can you share CSS property that you have written.

Answer (score 0):

overide the rules with the following ones:

```
.top-bar input {
    height: auto;
    padding-top: 0.35rem;
    padding-bottom: 0.35rem;
    font-size: 0.75rem;
}
@media only screen and (min-width:40.06em)
.top-bar input, .top-bar .button {
    font-size: 0.77rem;
    position: relative;
    top: 7px;
}
.top-bar .button {
    padding-top: 0.45rem;
    padding-bottom: 0.35rem;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    font-size: 0.75rem;
}
```

this will solve yout problem

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I added a custom class to the input field "searchinput"

```
.searchinput {
 height: 30px !important;
}
```

Still, I have to figure out why the demos on the Foundation website don't have this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I used the below to get it exactly right.
Credit to both posters above. If only I could vote....

```
.searchinput {height: 30px !important;}
```

I applied this to both the button and the text box. I found that if you just shrink the text box then the fix breaks in firefox. So I made both equal height.